# CoffeeScript way to define Angular services

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

Coffee script gives us an approaches to create and work with classes. I'm trying to use this approaches and define classes in separate files to use them as services:

```
class @Account
  isLoaded: no
  blahblah: ->
      ....


app.service('Account', ['$cookieStore', '$http', Account])
```

Very common issue for most entities in application, is some CRUD actions. Since I'm using services (if they are singletons and factories and if they not) to describe those entities, I now face the problem to extend my service class from $resource. Obviously, I can't just use it in standard coffeescript's way:

```
class @Account extends $resource
```

And for now the only solution I found is to change class prototype in module configuration:

```
app.service('Account', ['$cookieStore', '$http', Account]) 
app.run (Account, $resource) ->
  Account.prototype = new ($resource API_PATH + '/asdasdasd')
```

Which, leads me to the problem where I can only use all $resource features after this point, not in services's class constructor. And hence, I should define some additional `setup` method and call it manually here.

Second problem is that all injectors got passed in constructor function and hence, all class methods that needs to use that injectors should be defined INSIDE constructor function

```
  constructor: ($cookieStore, $http) ->
    console.log 'constructed'
    @addresses = [
      new AccountAddress('billing')
      new AccountAddress('shipping')
    ]
    @fetch = ->
      console.log 'here I can use $cookieStore and $http'
  foo: ->
    console.log 'here I can`t use $cookieStore and $http'
```

And that's does not look good.

Are there any ways to handle this problems?

Main idea for this was taken from first answer in [this google groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/56sdORWEoqg/b8hdPskxZXsJ)

Comment: Personally, I would highly discourage you from using classes for angular - in my experience, it just does not go along well.

Comment: @Florian, seems like that. But maybe before close this idea I decided to at least ask community. Who know, maybe there are ways which I failed to see )

Comment: Well I tried in a recent project (without success) - if your main concern is having multiple files for multiple services, you can just merge them on build.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following syntax for controllers:

```
app = angular.module 'myapp', []

class MySimpleCtrl

  @$inject: ['$scope'] 
  constructor: (@scope) ->
    @scope.demo = 'demo value'
    @scope.clearText = @clearText

  clearText: =>
    @scope.demo = ""

app.controller 'MySimpleCtrl', MySimpleCtrl

angular.bootstrap document, ['myapp']
```

Take a look at this jsFiddle:
     http://jsfiddle.net/jwcMA/